SOAP request Converting circular structure to JSON
I am creating an endpoint that will make a request to a SOAP service with soap npm library. This is the imlementation I'm using.
import xml2js from "xml2js";

const soap = require('soap');
const wsdlPath = 'path_to_wsdl.wsdl';
const endPoint = endpoint_to_service;

const clientOptions = {
  disableCache: false,
  endpoint: endPoint,
  escapeXML: false,
  preserveWhitespace: true,
};

let soapClient = await soap.createClientAsync(wsdlPath, clientOptions);
//privateKey and cert are the variables containing my certificates for the service
soapClient.setSecurity(new soap.WSSecurityCert(privateKey, cert));
soapClient.addHttpHeader('Content-Type', 'application/soap+xml');

const builder = new xml2js.Builder({
  headless: true,
  rootName: "servicerequest",
});

//variable request being an object with the parameters for the service
const xml = builder.buildObject(request);
const result = (await soapClient.methodAsync({
  _xml: xml,
}));

The problem is when the code is executed, I get the following error
ERROR   Invoke Error    
{
  "errorType": "TypeError",
  "errorMessage": "Converting circular structure to JSON\n    --> starting at object with constructor 'ClientRequest'\n    |     property 'socket' -> object with constructor 'TLSSocket'\n    --- property '_httpMessage' closes the circle",
  "stack": [
    "TypeError: Converting circular structure to JSON",
    "    --> starting at object with constructor 'ClientRequest'",
    "    |     property 'socket' -> object with constructor 'TLSSocket'",
    "    --- property '_httpMessage' closes the circle",
    "    at JSON.stringify (<anonymous>)",
    "    at t.savePaymentHandler (/var/task/src/v1/functions/savePayment/index.js:8:706225)",
    "    at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5)",
    "    at async /var/task/src/v1/functions/savePayment/index.js:8:923167"
  ]
}

I'm not sure where or why this error is coming up. I would appreciate for any insights on this issue

most probably its failing before even sending it out to the server, so check your message thoroughly, it must have some circular objects, hence causing this serialization error.
